# Pascal extension on VSCODE (pascal auto indent)

Tags: visual-studio-code, pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to use pascal on vscode and i had to download some extensions, one of them ('Pascal formatter) what me to config this variables:
Indicates the engine app path (required)
  "pascal.formatter.enginePath":

Indicates the configuration file for the selected engine (optional)
  "pascal.formatter.engineParameters": 
But im on ubuntu and i dont know where is that, bc the enginepath default its "C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-win32\ptop.exe". what i need to do here?
I want to use this extension because vscode its not auto-indenting my code while i write it.

If i write this in vscode :

```
program example;
var
i:integer;
begin
i:=4;
i:=4+5;
end.
```

but i want the code to autoindent while im writing like this:

```
program example;
var(*after hit enter it  autoindent*)
   i:integer;
begin(*after hit enter autoindent*)
   i:=4;
   i:=4+5;
end.(*detect end and get it to the same indent than begin*)
```

Comment: If you are using FreePascal, why not just use the freeware IDE for it, Lazarus?  It works perfectly on Ubuntu in my experience.

Comment: I tried but is complex, for example i want to have at the left a file explorer so i can switch fast from files but i dont know the maximum i did is just create a project but i had to add by one the files, i cant open a folder